# Query with pyspark an Elasticsearch index: how to specify es.nodes?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark

I'm trying to query with pyspark an Elasticsearch index but without success:

```
] ./bin/pyspark --driver-class-path=jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.0.jar
```

In ipython, spark version 2.0.1:

```
In [1]: es_read_conf = { "es.resource" : "test/docs" , "es.nodes" : ["xx.xx.xx.aa","xx.xx.xx.bb","xx.xx.xx.cc"],"es.port" : "9200", "es.net.http.auth.user": "myusername", "es.net.http.auth.pass": "mypassword"}
es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=es_read_conf)
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

It seems that there's a problem converting the python list of es.nodes into a Java string. I tried with a string consisting only of the address of my elasticsearch master node ("xx.xx.xx.aa") but I get another error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [HEAD] on [test/docs] failed; server[xx.xx.xx.bb:9202] returned [502|Bad Gateway:]
```

Sometimes the error refers to data node bb, sometimes to cc. Interestingly, if I run the same command multiple times, it happens that I get no error (maybe it's when the query is run only against the master node?). I have no problem running the command with localhost as the only es.nodes.

Answer (score 0):

see ES-hadoop documentation[enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#cfg-network)

you need to set the following property to spark conf:

```
conf.set("es.nodes","<your host>")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lior. I tried your suggestion but ir raises the same error.

Comment: you should put only one of the nodes ES have self discovery capabilities..
pass it as string (not a list)

Comment: that's what I did at first but I tried also with a list of nodes. No success.